# How can I play sound directly after an other?

Tags: audio, click, playback

I would like to play a sound when I click on an image. But when I quickly click on it again, it doesn't play it again because the other is not finished. How can I adjust this?

My code:

```
var click;
click = new Audio("sound/ping.mp3")
click.volume = .75;

circle.on("click", handleMouseEventClick);

function handleMouseEventClick(evt){
    click.play();
    punten += 1;
    score.text = "Score: " + punten;
    stage.removeChild(this);
    stage.update();
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function handleMouseEventClick(evt){
  if(!click.paused){
    click.pause();
    click.currentTime = 0;
    click.play();
  }
  else click.play();
}
```